# What are the key differences between a particle and a wave?

Tags: wave-particle-duality

When do we call something a particle, and when do we call something a wave? Do we call something a particle when it is highly localized? If that's right, then a wave packet is a particle. Do we call something a wave when it is not localized and when it shows interference pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do we call something a particle when it is highly localized?

yes

> If that's right, then a wave packet is a particle.

In quantum optics, photons are often represented as localized "wave packets". The "field theory" method of determining if something is a "particle" is if it obeys a particular commutation relation. Often times this leads concluding that in some interacting systems, so part of the system has this particular commutation relation and it's called a "quasi-particle". For example, the interaction between atomic dipoles and photons are labeled "[polaritons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polariton)" and are considered a type of "quasi-particles" because of their [commutation behavior](https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.84.5094):
$$\left[\hat{\Psi}_k,\hat{\Psi}^+_{k'}\right]
 =\delta_{k,k'}\left[\cos^2\theta
 +\sin^2\theta\frac{1}{N} \sum_j(\hat{\sigma}^j_{bb}+\hat{\sigma}^j_{cc}) \right].$$

> Do we call something a wave when it is not localized and when it shows
>   interference pattern?

Yes. Although this is the trickiest to answer. Wave are things that have multiple values distributed across space and follow some sort of differential-equation that looks like a wave. I'm careful not to say that "waves follow the wave equation" because quantum waves do not follow this (they follow something that behaves pretty "wave-like" resembling a complex version of the heat equation).

Electrical waves follow the wave equation (through a simplification of Maxwell's equations).

Classical particles (in some materials, like water or air, for example) are held-together with a particular force (a harmonic oscillator usually) and can be shown to follow each other in a way that follows the wave equation.

Quantum waves follow Schrödinger's equation.

Photons follow both the wave equation and Schrödinger's equation.

Comment: Schrodinger’s equation is non-relativistic and doesn’t apply to photons.

Comment: [Here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0911.4682.pdf) is a modern example the time evolution of a photon wavepacket being solved for in the "schrodinger picture." (when it interacts with a second photon in a kerr media). Do you have some sort of problem with this treatment (which I believe to be fairly standard in quantum optics)?

Answer (score 2):

If a state is localized in position basis then it is called a particle (something that has a definite position) and if it is localized in the momentum basis then it is called a wave (something that has a definite wavelength, which, in Quantum Mechanics, relates to the momentum).

Having said that, I would add that in practice, any quantum state that is fairly distributed in the position basis is called a wave. It is not a strict definition. Moreover, it should also be noted that what we call the wave-function (i.e., the position basis representation of the quantum state) is not a wave in a mathematical sense, i.e., [the equation according to which it evolves in time (the Schrödinger equation) is not a wave equation, it is a diffusion equation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/465998/20427). So, to be honest, we simply mean a distributed or a little bit wiggly pattern when we say "wave" in the context of Quantum Mechanics. A more precise definition would be a distribution that has a specific wavelength (i.e., a specific momentum) as I mentioned, however, even such a wave-function wouldn't follow the wave-equation as it evolves, it would follow the Schrödinger equation (i.e., a diffusion equation).

Finally, all quantum states exhibit interference. However, you are correct in noticing that particle-like states wouldn't exhibit any distinctive interference-like behavior in the position basis. But, any wavefunction that has a distributed or a little bit wiggly pattern would exhibit noticeable interference, in particular, one doesn't need a distribution with a specific wavelength to exhibit interference.

Comment: I don't agree with this. In principle I can make a very localized sound wave. How would that be a particle? On the other hand an electron can be delocalized. Why does that make it a wave?

Comment: @my2cts Oh, of course, I didn't mean that any localized wave is a particle. I just meant that a quantum state whose position basis representation is localized is a particle. An electron, when it is, for example, in a momentum eigenstate, exhibits wave-like properties rather than particle-like properties in the language of the early days of quantum mechanics when people used to talk about wave-particle duality, etc.